# PHP Search database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, pdo

I thought this would be a fairly simple task but I keep getting this error when I try to search now "**Notice: Array to string conversion in xxxxxxxx.php**".

My code is pretty simple and is as follows:

```
<?php
$content .= "<h1>Search for a comic</h1>";

$form_html = "<form action='' method='POST' >
    <fieldset><label>Name: <input type='text' name='search_title'  placeholder='Title'></label>
    </fieldset><fieldset>
    <input type='submit' value='Search' name='submit'>
    </fieldset>
</form>";

$content .= $form_html;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $input_search = $_POST['search_title'];

    $results = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM Comic WHERE name LIKE ?');
    $results->execute(array('%'.$input_search.'%'));
    $all_results = $results->fetchAll();
    $content .= $all_results;

}
?>
```

I've read loads of other similar questions and tried a few different ways of doing this but none have worked so far.

Bit of further info. $content is echoed by my index so its all displayed.
My database has a table called 'Comics' with like 9 columns, the 2nd of which is 'name'. I want the user to be able to type in a single word or complete title and have a list of all the comics with that word or title be shown to them (e.g: I search 'Doomsday' or 'Atomic Skull' and the comics 'Doomsday is Here!' and 'Curse of the Atomic Skull' are shown).

Comment: `$all_results` is an array, so try `print_r($content);` You may want to rethink your logic a bit to get what you want from the array and tacking *that* to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $input_search = $_POST['search_title'];

    $results = $link->prepare('SELECT name FROM Comic WHERE name LIKE ?');
    $results->execute(array('%'.$input_search.'%'));
    $all_results = $results->fetchAll();
    $row_cnt = $results->rowCount();

    if($row_cnt == 0){
        $content .= "There are no results.";
    }else {
        foreach ($all_results as $row1){
            foreach ($row1 as $data){
                $content .= $data ."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I output the results but there is two of each result (print_r as suggested above showed me something like this:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Man of Steel [0] => Man of Steel ) [1] => Array ( [name] => The Kid Who Talks to Superman [0] => The Kid Who Talks to Superman ) )

Answer (score 0):

`$results->fetchAll();` returns an array of remaining rows in the result set. Not a string. So doing `$content .= $all_results;` is trying to append an array to a string.

You'll want to loop over each of the items in the array it provides, then you can do what you want with them.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php can help you.

Comment: I tried that though with this and it didn't work:

 foreach($all_results as $row){
        $content .= $row;
    }

Comment: $row is an array too. Do the print_r I suggested so you can visualize your array @c.timothy

Comment: `$row` is an array of each of the separate fields / columns in the row.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I half fixed it! For some reason I'm getting double of each result. I had to use two foreach statements as each row was an array